# How to validate if a date indicated as a string belongs to an interval of 2 dates indicated in another string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, date, datetime

```py
import os, datetime

content = os.listdir("when")
print(content)
#this print...
#['2022_-_12_-_29 12pp33 am _--_ 2023_-_01_-_25 19pp13 pm.txt', '2023-02-05 00pp00 am.txt']

for i in range(len(content)):
    content[i] = content[i].replace("_-_", "-").replace("pp", ":")
print(content) #I prepare the input to use it to search
#this print...
#['2022-12-29 12:33 am _--_ 2023-01-25 19:13 pm.txt', '2023-02-05 00:00 am.txt']

input_to_search_in_folder = "2022_-_01_-_05 12:33 am"  #file data to find in the 'when' folder
```

I have changed the `:` to `pp` (referring to point-point) because you cannot place `:` in folders or/and files, at least not in Windows

```
2022_-_12_-_29 12pp33 am _--_ 2023_-_01_-_25 19pp13 pm
            initial date _--_ final date
```

In this case `input_to_search_in_folder = "2022_-_01_-_05 12:33 am"` does not match a file with a specific date name. But if it belongs to the interval of days indicated in the file name `'2022_-_12_-_29 12pp33 am _--_ 2023_-_01_-_25 19pp13 pm.txt'`

How could I validate that this date `"2022_-_01_-_05 12:33 am"` does belong to that time interval `'2022_-_12_-_29 12pp33 am _--_ 2023_-_01_-_25 19pp13 pm'` or if it's this date `'2023-02-05 00:00 am'`?

If the validation is successful, the program should print the content inside that .txt (in this case inside the `2022_-_12_-_29 12pp33 am _--_ 2023_-_01_-_25 19pp13 pm.txt` )

```py
text_file = open("when/" + , "r")
data_inside_this_file = text_file.read()
text_file.close()

#And finally prints the content of the .txt file that matches the date specified in the 'input_to_search_in_folder' variable
print(repr(data_inside_this_file))
```

Comment: Are you able to change the file naming scheme?  If the filename looked like `2022_05_01_1233` (with 24-hour times), you could compare it directly as a string.

Comment: american dates :')

Comment: @JohnGordon All the logic of the program is designed under the most international standard possible, which is the one used by the `datetime` library. This is  `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm am or pm`. and the intervals are expressed as `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm am or pm _--_ YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm am or pm`, which seeks to coincide with any date that is in the middle of those 2 (including them).

Comment: A useful regex pattern to extract **date range bounds** (then I need the interval and not only the bounds) could be `(d*_-_\d{2}_-_\d{2}\s*\(\d{2}:\d{2}\ s*(?:am|pm)\))_--_(d*_-_\d{2}_-_\d{2}\s*\(\d{2}:\d{2 }\s*(?:am|pm)\))` in this case I could get two capture groups, the first capture the first date-time, and the second capture the second date-time

Comment: Why `19:13 pm` instead of `7:13 pm` or `19:13`  ?

Comment: @Amessihel Because the program follows a storage standard, ie it will always put 'am' or 'pm' after it. You can still assume the 24 hour format and simply use a .remove() to remove those 'am' or 'pm' indications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would clean the strings fully, convert them to datetime objects (because these can be compared to each other), then compare then and you have the result and can do whatever with it:

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime


content = os.listdir("when")
print(content)
#['2022_-_12_-_29 12pp33 am _--_ 2023_-_01_-_25 19pp13 pm.txt', '2023-02-05 00pp00 am.txt']

for i in range(len(content)):
    content[i] = content[i].replace("_-_", "-").replace("pp", ":")
#['2022-12-29 12:33 am _--_ 2023-01-25 19:13 pm.txt', '2023-02-05 00:00 am.txt']

cleaned_filename = os.path.splitext(content[0])[0] #="2022-12-29 12:33 am _--_ 2023-01-25 19:13 pm"
start_dt = datetime.strptime(content[0].split(" _--_ ")[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#="2022-12-29 12:33 am" = datetime(2022, 12, 29, 12, 33)
last_dt = datetime.strptime(content[0].split(" _--_ ")[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#="2023-01-25 19:13 pm"
third_dt = datetime.strptime(os.path.splitext(content[1])[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#="2023-02-05 00:00 am"

input_to_search = "2022_-_01_-_05 12:33 am".replace("_-_", "-") 
#"2022-01-05 12:33 am".
input_dt = datetime.strptime(input_to_search, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#="datetime(2022, 01, 05, 12, 33)"

if start_dt <= input_dt <= last_dt:
    print("in between")
elif input_dt == third_dt:
    print("Match")
else:
    print("No!")
```

Comment: This give me a `NameError: name 'splittext' is not defined`, In this case, How and where should I define that method or variable so that it does not cause problems?

Comment: @Matt095 Oops sorry, its a method from os.path, so import os.path

Answer (score 1):

A way is to extract the dates using regex and then convert them as date like mrblue6's answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from datetime import datetime
import re

# Let's assume this is one of the directory entries
direntry='2022_-_12_-_29 12pp33 am _--_ 2023_-_01_-_25 19pp13 pm.txt'

# We exclude in the regex the AM/PM part since the format is 24-hour clock
datePattern = '(\d{4}_-_\d{2}_-_\d{2} \d{2}pp\d{2}) [ap]m'
dirPattern =  f'{datePattern} _--_ {datePattern}.txt'

# Let's extract the "milestone" dates
matches = re.search(dirPattern, direntry)
extractedDate1 = matches.group(1)
extractedDate2 = matches.group(2)

# Let's extract the date to check
matches = re.search(datePattern, "2022_-_01_-_05 12pp33 am")
extractedDateToCheck = matches.group(1)

# Let's convert them as date time
readDateFormat = '%Y_-_%m_-_%d %Hpp%M'
date1 = datetime.strptime(extractedDate1, readDateFormat)
date2 = datetime.strptime(extractedDate2, readDateFormat)
dateToCheck = datetime.strptime(extractedDateToCheck, readDateFormat)

# Let's compare them
print (f"Date 1 :        {date1}")
print (f"Date 2 :        {date2}")
print (f"Date to check:  {dateToCheck}")
print (f"Check:          {date1 <= dateToCheck <= date2}" )
```

Output:

```
Date 1 :        2022-12-29 12:33:00
Date 2 :        2023-01-25 19:13:00
Date to check:  2022-01-05 12:33:00
Check:          False
```